# Event-listener implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, event-handling, lambda

While writing a C++ GUI application more or less from scratch I needed some form of an event-listener system, preferably using lambdas. An event should be able to have multiple listeners and the user should not have to worry about the lifetime of the objects. I came up with this bit using shared and weak pointers to determine object lifetime:

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>


template <typename ... Args> struct event:public std::shared_ptr<std::list<std::function<void(Args...)>>>{

  using handler = std::function<void(Args...)>;
  using listener_list = std::list<handler>;

  struct listener{
    std::weak_ptr<listener_list> the_event;
    typename listener_list::iterator it;

    listener(){ }

    listener(event & s,handler f){
      observe(s,f);
    }

    listener(listener &&other){
      the_event = other.the_event;
      it = other.it;
      other.the_event.reset();
    }

    listener(const listener &other) = delete;

    listener & operator=(const listener &other) = delete;

    listener & operator=(listener &&other){
      reset();
      the_event = other.the_event;
      it = other.it;
      other.the_event.reset();
      return *this;
    }

    void observe(event & s,handler f){
      reset();
      the_event = s;
      it = s->insert(s->end(),f);
    }

    void reset(){
      if(!the_event.expired()) the_event.lock()->erase(it);
      the_event.reset();
    }

    ~listener(){ reset(); }
  };

  event():std::shared_ptr<listener_list>(std::make_shared<listener_list>()){ }
  event(const event &) = delete;
  event & operator=(const event &) = delete;

  void notify(Args... args){
    for(auto &f:**this) f(args...);
  }

  listener connect(handler h){
    return listener(*this,h);
  }

};
```

Example usage:

```
#include <iostream>

using click_event = event<float,float>;

struct gui_element{
  click_event click;
  void mouse_down(float x,float y){ click.notify(x, y); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  gui_element A,B;
  click_event::listener listener_1,listener_2;

  listener_1.observe(A.click,[](float x,float y){ std::cout << "l1 : A was clicked at " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; });
  listener_2.observe(B.click,[](float x,float y){ std::cout << "l2 : B was clicked at " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; });

  {
  auto temporary_listener = A.click.connect([](float x,float y){ std::cout << "tmp: A was clicked at " << x << ", " << y << std::endl; });
  // A has two listeners, B has one listeners
  A.mouse_down(1, 0);
  B.mouse_down(0, 1);
  }

  listener_2 = std::move(listener_1);

  // A has one listener, B has no listeners
  A.mouse_down(2, 0);
  B.mouse_down(0, 2);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> l1 : A was clicked at 1, 0
> tmp: A was clicked at 1, 0
> l2 : B was clicked at 0, 1
> l1 : A was clicked at 2, 0
> ```

While the usage is exactly how I wanted, I am not sure the implementation is elegant or optimal. Any way how to improve this?

Comment: In other words, you reimplemented signals, right? :)

Comment: I'm not sure about the correct terminology but something like that, yeah ;-)

Comment: I you rename `event` into `signal`, `notify` into `emit` and `observe` into `connect`, it sems that what you've got are indeed signals :p

Comment: So are the terms event and listener incorrect then? (this is my first real gui project so I chose the names to sound intuitive to me)

Comment: No no, they are fine. The only strange name is `observe` since it's the listener/observes which should "observe", not the event. Or at least I think so.

Comment: True, it is kind of backwards. I'll go with "connect" in this case then :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in the comments, your system is pretty close to a system of [signals and slots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots). Congratulations if you never heard of the pattern before, that's an excellent way to implement an the observer design pattern! I still have few notes:

- I don't know which compiler you use, but mine won't compile your code unless I include `<memory>` for `std::shared_ptr`. I suppose that it may be transitively included from `<functional>` or `<list>` in your implementation. Never rely on transitive includes from the standard library and always include the exact header that contains what you need.
- Qt, which is the emblematic library when it comes to signals and slots, tends to use past participle for its signas names. For example, instead of `click`, it would be `clicked`:

  ```
  button.clicked.connect(/* whatever */);
  ```

  It allows to read the line easily as "when button is clicked, do whatever". Also, it makes the object look more like a trigger and less like an action.
- From a design point of view, `connect` being a method taking only one function, I would expect it to add the function to the list, not to return a `listener`.
- You should encapsulate `std::shared_ptr<std::list<std::function<void(Args...)>>>` instead of inheriting from it. Frankly, you don't want people to expose every method of `std::shared_ptr`. You don't want people to think of pointers when they want events, right?

The truth is my answer isn't really personal. Since your class obviously looks like a signal class, everything I am saying tends to mean "make your design closer to those of existing signal classes like [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/signals2.html)" :/

Comment: Awesome feedback, every point is useful to me - thanks :-) FYI I'll update the question with the improved code

Comment: @Lars Don't. Once a question is answered, you can't edit the code in the question in the manner that would invalidate the answers. That's one of the main site rules. See our [help centre](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.